# write a block in plsql following output

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I want some PL/SQL code which prints 1 to 100. Additionally for numbers divisible by 3 print `'wel'`, for numbers divisible by 5 print `'come'` and for numbers divisible by 3 and 5  then print `'welcome'`. Output like this

```
    1
    2
    wel
    4
    come
    7
    .
    .
    14
   welcome
```

Here is some code I  have written:

```
begin
    for i in 1..100 loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i);
       if  mod(i,3)=0 then
            dbms_output.put_line('wel');
        elsif mod(i,5)=0 then
            dbms_output.put_line('come');
        elsif mod(i,3)=0 and mod(i,5)=0 then
            dbms_output.put_line('welcome');
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: The problem with the code you have posted is that it lists the condition test in the wrong order. A value of `15` is both divisible by `3` and by `5`: so it you want to do something specific for multiples of `15` you need to test for divisible by 15 **before** testing for either divisible by 3 or divisible by 5. More generally, put start switch evaluations (`case`, `if ... elsif..`) with the most specific condition and progress towards the most general (the most general of all of course being `else`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like variation of [Fizzbuzz interview question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15623/fizzbuzz-really). You could use single query:

```
SELECT nvl(decode(mod(rownum,3),0,'wel')||decode(mod(rownum,5),0,'come'),rownum)
       as Example
FROM xmltable('1 to 100');
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d375a24fc142b3786029ca02ca51c0ac)**

## EDIT

PL/SQL block:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (
  SELECT nvl(decode(mod(rownum,3),0,'wel')||decode(mod(rownum,5),0,'come'),rownum)
       as Example
  FROM xmltable('1 to 100')) LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.Example);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7cea992dce874f15514591473602c75b)**

## EDIT 2

As you posted your code is is very easy to fix it:

```
begin
for i in 1..100 loop
  if mod(i,3)=0 and mod(i,5)=0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('welcome');
  elsif mod(i,5)=0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('come');
  elsif mod(i,3)=0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('wel');
  else 
   dbms_output.put_line(i);
  end if;
end loop;
end;
//
```

**[DBFiddle Demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=52d5a427d049c80f3e0577ce4c033d29)**

Comment: Please read I want a Ans in PLSQL And printing a Number 1 to 100 In For Loop Then I want to use If, elsif statements

Comment: @lukasz_szozda Thank you sir, But I need explanation why u change that order ??

Comment: I will take some credit for this: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3000  cheers!

Comment: @KaushikNayak That's really great :)